# Emacs org mode as a work diary

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is emacs org mode a good choice if you want to maintain a work diary?

I have tried to use it and archive old tasks (`TODO`s) but is there an easy way see which tasks I worked on for example last week (some task have been timestamped more than one day) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To see what I have done by day (there is probably a way to limit it to a particular period of time, but putting that together is a low priority for me), here is what I do. Start with <kbd>C-c a</kbd> that brings up the orgmode agenda menu, then <kbd>L</kbd> to display the timeline for the current file and finally <kbd>l</kbd> to turn log mode on.

That gives me output that looks like this:

```
...
Wednesday   9 March 2011
Clocked:   (7:21) One of my tasks
Clocked:   (0:07) Another of my tasks
...
```

Given that this is in emacs, there is probably a way to make this simpler/quicker to use, but this is what I do at the moment.

Comment: Ah oki, will try that!

Answer (score 3):

I personally have a binding to insert a *now* timestamp, and scatter them over the tasks I work on while I do so. Then, I can see what I've been doing in the agenda (<kbd>C-a a a</kbd>), looking at past days.
<sup>Maybe rayners' idea of the timeline is better, I just never used it.</sup>
It has the advantage you can put multiple temistamps for some tasks, without depending on state changes (which I personaly don't log).

It goes :

```lisp
;; Insert immediate active timestamp
(define-key global-map (kbd "<f9>")
'(lambda () (interactive)
   (when (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
     (org-insert-time-stamp nil t nil)
     ;; (insert "\n")
     )))
```

And may requiere `org-agenda-skip-timestamp-if-done` to be `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use clocking, you can generate a week view of what you have done (clocked in/out total hours) in your org file with this code block

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :scope agenda :block thisweek :step day
#+END:
```

and `C-c C-c` on the header BEGIN to populate. I have left the above options that I use to show what is possible (week view step by day). Only problem I face with this, I forget to clock in everything I do! I complement it with an `org-journal` entry when I know I haven't clocked in staff.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it yet, but org-mode can be used to clock your working times. See :   http://orgmode.org/manual/Clocking-work-time.html

Comment: mm using that but how do you generate a what happened that day view?